# How method hiding works in Java?

Tags: java, method-hiding, member-hiding

```
class Penguin {
    public static int getHeight() {
        return 3;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(this.getHeight());
    }
}

public class CrestedPenguin extends Penguin {
    public static int getHeight() {
        return 8;
    }

    public static void main(String... fish) {
        new CrestedPenguin().printInfo();
    }
}
```

This code output 3.
I don't understand the output. I expected 8 because of method hiding.
I looked on the internet for method hiding and I understand this concept, but I don't understand why  the `getHeight` method called is the one in Penguin instead of the one in `Crested Penguin` since the reference is of a `CrestedPenguin` type.

Update: i want to mention that this is an educational code and it is not intended for production purpose. I am preparing for the Java OCP.

Comment: You're thinking that `CrestedPenguin()` should dictate which `getHeight()` is called, but that reference is irrelevant; because the static type that the compiler sees is the only one on which `getHeight()` is called (directly). `this` in `Penguing` can **only** be `Penguin`, and that's why the compiler picks the method in `Penguin`. Beside that, you should avoid invoking static methods on instances, and the biggest reason for that is the potential to lead to the confusion you're experiencing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not actually sure how this works either, because I would never do this and have never had a need to. If you remove the `static` modifier, that's a more real world use case and should behave as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this code snippet is that you added `static` keyword in `getHeight()` function. We cannot override static function because we don't need an object to access the function. Changing it to

```
class Penguin {
    public int getHeight() { return 3; }
    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(this.getHeight());
    }
}
public class CrestedPenguin extends Penguin {
    public int getHeight() { return 8; }
    public static void main(String... fish) {
        new CrestedPenguin().printInfo();
    }
}
```

Will override `getHeight()` function of Penguin.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are preparing for the OCP exam... I would like to expand what causes the method hiding behavior, in case you face similar problems:

> The following list summarizes the five rules for hiding a method:
>
> 1. The method in the child class must have the same signature as the method in the parent class.
> 2. The method in the child class must be at least as accessible or more accessible than the method in the parent class.
> 3. The method in the child class may not throw a checked exception that is new or broader than the class of any exception thrown in the
>    parent class method.
> 4. If the method returns a value, it must be the same or a subclass of the method in the parent class, known as covariant return types.
> 5. The method defined in the child class must be marked as static if it is marked as static in the parent class (method hiding). Likewise,
>    the method must not be marked as static in the child class if it is
>    not marked as static in the parent class (method overriding).

This is quoted from "OCA Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer Study Guide Exam 1", I suggest reading it for preparing for OCP, because it covers in all possible details the core features of Java, unlike the OCP books I've seen.

Comment: thanks for your ressponse. indeed i'm using this book for the preparation and this code is from this book